# Prevent pandas resample from filling in gap day while downsampling

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample

I have a pandas Series with measurements at a 1 minute interval. I want to downsample this data to a 5 minute interval. `series` contains measurements from at end of October 18th, none from October 19th and then measurements at the start of October 20th. Using `series.resample("5T").mean()` fills October 19th with `NaN`'s, and `series.resample("5T").sum()` fills the missing day with `0`'s:

```
index1 = pd.date_range("2023-10-18 23:50", "2023-10-18 23:59", freq="T")
index2 = pd.date_range("2023-10-20 00:00", "2023-10-20 00:10", freq="T")
series1 = pd.Series(range(len(index1)), index=index1)
series2 = pd.Series(range(100, len(index2)+100), index=index2)
series = pd.concat([series1, series2])

series.resample("5T").mean()
```

Out:

```
2023-10-18 23:50:00      2.0
2023-10-18 23:55:00      7.0
2023-10-19 00:00:00      NaN
2023-10-19 00:05:00      NaN
2023-10-19 00:10:00      NaN
                       ...  
2023-10-19 23:50:00      NaN
2023-10-19 23:55:00      NaN
2023-10-20 00:00:00    102.0
2023-10-20 00:05:00    107.0
2023-10-20 00:10:00    110.0
Freq: 5T, Length: 293, dtype: float64
```

I need  `pd.Series.resample` to stick to the days that are in `series` and not fill in anything for the missing day. How can this be done?

Comment: You could just keep rows where the date of the index exists in the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider grouping by the date first, then resampling.

```
series.groupby(series.index.date).resample("5T").mean()
```

```
2023-10-18  2023-10-18 23:50:00      2.0
            2023-10-18 23:55:00      7.0
2023-10-20  2023-10-20 00:00:00    102.0
            2023-10-20 00:05:00    107.0
            2023-10-20 00:10:00    110.0
dtype: float64
```

Add `.droplevel(0)` if you don't want the date in the output.